# Why Do I get an error 403 from the GCP Composer Airflow?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow-webserver

Yesterday, we set up an airflow environment in the GCP composer.
However, when I click on the Airflow web UI link, I get an error 403, with the note:

```
'403. That's an error.
That's all we know'
```

I cannot seem to solve the issue.
I have tried restarting the airflow environment/server, and also ensure that my ip is added to the web access control, but nothing works.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Do you have sufficient permissions to access the Web UI? You can find more about access controls to Web UI from here https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/composer-2/airflow-rbac

Comment: I did bullet point 2 under Register users in the Airflow UI. Not sure what else is needed.  I got granted as many rights as I could find in the documentation ...

Comment: Can you paste the output of below command? Replace PROJECT_ID with Composer project id and UI_USER with the email id of the user who is trying to access the Web UI


`gcloud projects get-iam-policy PROJECT_ID --flatten="bindings[].members" --format='table(bindings.role)' --filter="bindings.members:user:UI_USER"`

Answer (score 1):

To solve it, in your cloud composer instance, go to **environment configuration**, next, go to the section **Network configuration**, and edit the **Web server access control** by adding your IP address (https://www.ipaddress.my/).

Be sure to follow your organization's policy before doing this.

Answer (score 0):

The end result was adding my ipV6 to the composer airflow environment, and not my ipV4.